# String deduction

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have table with three columns: CG, TG and TG+ in the following format:

| CG | TG | TG_plus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B13+ | B13+ KNIT TOPS | B13+ KNIT TOPS T-SHIRTS S-SL |
| B13+ | G13+ WOVEN | G13+ WOVEN TOPS SHIRTS L-SL |

I need to obtain only KNIT TOPS from CG and T-SHIRTS S-SL from TG_plus.
result:

| CG | TG | TG_plus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B13+ | KNIT TOPS | T-SHIRTS S-SL |
| B13+ | WOVEN | TOPS SHIRTS L-SL |

I haven't found any information of string deduction. Is it possible?

I did it by means of cycle

```
a = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    b = df1['TG_plus'][i][len(df1['TG'][i]):]
    a.append(b)
df1['a'] = a
```

Are there any other ways to solve this task?

Comment: Why "B13+" in cell (col CG, row 2) and not "G13+"? (Do you use Pandas?)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Pandas`:

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: {'CG': x['CG'],
                          'TG': x['TG'][len(x['CG']):].strip(),
                          'TG_plus': x['TG_plus'][len(x['TG']):].strip()},
               axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
     CG         TG           TG_plus
0  B13+  KNIT TOPS     T-SHIRTS S-SL
1  G13+      WOVEN  TOPS SHIRTS L-SL
```